# Heroku Connect & PostGreSQL Events

Tags: heroku, sqlalchemy, salesforce, heroku-postgres, heroku-connect

Is there a practical way for my app to get notified when Heroku Connect adds records to a table?

I currently have a Flask app connected to a Salesforce org via Heroku Connect. I have event listeners for `before_insert`, `after_insert`, `before_update`, `after_update`. Additionally, SQLALCHEMY_ECHO is set to True. When I create a record in Salesforce, none of the event listeners fire, and no SQL statements are printed. However, if I query the model that matches the mapped sObject, I can see the new record. Therefore, Heroku Connect must be updating the table, but in a way that doesn't trigger event listeners. I did read up a bit on pg_notify (LSITEN), but all solutions seem to involve a `select` loop, which is much less elegant than `db.event.listens_for` decorators.

Comment: As I've dug more into this, it seems that SQLAlchemy only knows about events that are routed through SQLAlchemy. Heroku Connect seems to be mainly interacting directly on the database and through triggers. It'd be great if the triggers could send NOTIFY messages when records are modified so that other frameworks could act on them.